# Shared Events between multiple instances of WPF Custom Controls

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I have a couple Custom User Controls written in C# using the composite User Control model (i.e. starting with a UserControl) and when used in isolation, I'm not seeing any problems. But when two instances of the same control are used within the same parent, they seem to be stealing each other's events.

Here is an example. I have a control that uses a ListView. On LayoutUpdated event, I am updating the width of the columns to adjust for content. Not that this adds any value to the question, but here's the code of the handler:

```
var view = transactionListView.View as GridView;
if (view == null) return;
view.Columns[0].Width = view.Columns[0].ActualWidth;
view.Columns[0].Width = double.NaN;
view.Columns[view.Columns.Count - 1].Width = view.Columns[view.Columns.Count - 1].ActualWidth;
view.Columns[view.Columns.Count - 1].Width = double.NaN;
const int dynamicColumnIndex = 2;
try
{
    var dynamicColumnWidth = view.Columns.Where((t, index) => dynamicColumnIndex != index)
       .Aggregate(transactionListView.ActualWidth, (current, t) => current - t.ActualWidth);
    view.Columns[dynamicColumnIndex].Width = dynamicColumnWidth - 25;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // log
}
```

Again, the sample above is just provided to provide some context, but the other controls that I'm referring to contain completely different implementations.

I thought if I provided an x:Name for the ListView within the control, it could help, but it didn't. Then I provided an x:Name for the custom control, when I use it. No difference.

The outcome of when I use this control with the ListView is that the second ListView is the only one that maintains the auto-size on the columns. The first one seems un-impacted.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do the event handlers not run? Or does it just not do what you think it should? Could you post short code that actually reproduces the problem?

Comment: In other instances, the behavior is more complex... but in this case it's quite straighforward. I have two of these controls in one view, the first one is showing the columns in default width, the second one is showing the columns with auto-width. The code snippet from above auto-sizes these columns. So it appears the second control (i.e. the one that was added last) is probably stealing the events of the first, so in both cases the auto-column-width is applying to the second.